# add / overwrite items to map and return the map

Tags: dart, maps

I need to add or overwrite items to a `LinkedHashMap` and at the same time it should return the map modified.

This is the code I have:

```
MyModel.fromJson(json);
```

`json` variable is `LinkedHashMap`, and I need to add items before calling `fromJson` function.

I tried with `addAll` function:

```
MyModel.fromJson(json.addAll({ ... }));
```

but it returns void so I can use for calling `fromJson` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [cascade notation](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#cascade-notation-) for calling a method on a object and still return the same object reference instead of the result of the method:

```
void main() {
  final map = {"A": 1};
  print(map..addAll({"B": 2})); // {A: 1, B: 2}
}
```